# How to join strings in Rails helper options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm fairly new to Rails. The code snippet in **Figure 1** is causing a rails exception **wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)** when the variable `asset_path` is added in front of the value of `original`.

**Figure 1: Rails image_tag**

```
<%= image_tag("foo/blank.gif", {
    :class =>"lazy", 
    :data => { "original" => asset_path + 'foo/image-01.png'}, 
    :alt => ""}) %>
```

The problem seems to lie with the way the two strings are joined:

```
asset_path + 'foo/image-01.png'
```

What is the correct way of joining two strings in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset path requires an argument and you're not passing one, which is why it's exploding. The proper way to do this would be to use `image_path`, which also requires an argument:

```
<%= image_tag("foo/blank.gif", {
    :class =>"lazy",
    :data => { "original" => image_path("foo/image-01.png")},
    :alt => ""}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you should use "asset_path" in your assets (javascript, css), for example:

```
$('#logo').attr({
  src: "<%= asset_path('logo.png') %>"
});
```

A must read to make up your mind: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html